# iOS draw a line inside a view while drawing over existing fields

Tags: ios, view, rendering

I have a view that has a bunch of labels and buttons on it with existing data. What I would like to do is to have a rounded rect with a group of labels and buttons inside them, I have about 2 groups and I would like each group to have their own rounded rect. Also I would like a line to separate the rounded rects from each other, but I heard that a label can do that just fine.

The reason I ask of this is because various tutorials and methods online specify to override the drawRect function. However, I am not sure if this will override any of my labels and buttons being rendered or their functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding drawRect for a view does not affect how any of its subviews are drawn, if that answers your question.

In other words, drawing a line in the background of a view will not change how labels or buttons inside that view are drawn.

However, for this effect I don't know if you need to use drawRect. If you import the QuartzCore library, you can draw a rounded rect using an ordinary view:

Just create an ordinary view behind or as a container for your buttons and labels and set it's layer.borderWidth, layer.borderColor and layer.cornerRadius properties.

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you.